# How to show field extension equality

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I've seen similar field extension questions on SE, but nothing with a third root, and I'm having trouble adapting any of those solutions to this problem.

So I'm trying to prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+{5}^{1/3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},{5}^{1/3})$.

Now, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},{5}^{1/3})$ contains both $\sqrt{2}$ and ${5}^{1/3}$, so $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+{5}^{1/3})\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},{5}^{1/3})$, right?

How then do I go about proving the reverse, that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},{5}^{1/3})\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+{5}^{1/3})$? I not even sure where to start. Any advice, tips?

Comment: You could show that $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt[3]{5}$ are both in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2} +\sqrt[3]{5})$.

Comment: That sounds like what I want to do, but I don't know how. I've tried raising it to a higher power, but the polynomial quickly gets unwieldy, and doesn't seem to simplify.

Comment: Try to immitate this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251741/how-to-show-two-field-extensions-are-equal?rq=1

Comment: Yes, I did see similar questions, but as I said, there is no third root in that question. While trying to use the same methods, the third root doesn't seem to ever go away. That's why I've created a new question, to see if I need a different approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An idea

$$r=\sqrt2+\sqrt[3]5\implies r^3-3\sqrt2\,r^2+6r-2\sqrt2=5\implies$$

$$(r^3+6r-5)^2=\left[(3r^2+2)\sqrt2\right]^2$$

The above shows that $\;\dim_{\Bbb Q}\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2+\sqrt[3]5)= 6\;$ (why? Show the polynomial $\;(r^3+6r-5)^2-\left[(3r^2+2)\sqrt2\right]^2\in\Bbb Q[x]\;$ is irreducible ), but since $\;\dim_{\Bbb Q}\Bbb Q(\sqrt2\,,\,\sqrt[3]5)=6\;$ (why?) and we already know $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt2+\sqrt[3]5)\le\Bbb Q(\sqrt2\,,\,\sqrt[3]5)\;$ we get equality.

Comment: Thanks for helping! I'm still a bit confused though. Basically, if two extensions have the same dimension, and one is a subset of the other, then they are equal? Is that formalized somewhere?

Comment: Of course it is: in linear algebra! If we have vector spaces $\;V,U\;$ **over the same field**, and $$(1)\;\;U\le V\;\;,\;\;(2)\;\;\dim U=\dim V<\infty \implies V=U$$ The proof is almost trivial.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! It seems obvious in the context of linear algebra, but my Abstract gut instinct is a bit more shaky. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Actually I found an even simpler way, after receiving some hints from my professor.

Let $\alpha=\sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{5}$, and notice that $(\alpha^2-2)/2\alpha=\sqrt[3]{5}$. Thus both $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt[3]{5}$ are in $Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{5})$, and the two field extensions must be equal.

Comment: Is this true? I seem to get an extra of $\sqrt{2} \sqrt[3]{5}$?

Comment: $\alpha^2-2=2\sqrt{2}\sqrt[3]{5}+\sqrt[3]{5}^2$ but $2\alpha\sqrt[3]{5}$ is not equal to this?

Comment: @DonAntonio ? Am I being dumb?

Comment: You're right, that doesn't seem to hold. I posted this a while ago, and I'm not quite sure what I got wrong. Sorry! DonAntonio's answer definitely helped solve the problem though.

Comment: There is way to find the correct answer: list $(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{5})^n$ for $n = 0,1,2,3,4,5$. Then make a combination of those, where it is allowed to divide too.
Example: the field extension $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{7})$ Let $\alpha = \sqrt 2 + \sqrt 7$ then $\sqrt 2 = \frac{\alpha^3-13\alpha}{10}$ and $\sqrt 7 = \frac{\alpha^3-23\alpha}{-10}$